# How to lock row for update in Ibm Db2 without timeouts?

Tags: sql, database, db2, mainframe, zos

I need to update one row per connection in ibm db2 on zos without data anomalies.

I choose FOR UPDATE WITH RS USE AND KEEP statement, but there is a problem. If one client is holding lock during data update and simultaneously second user tries to read the same row - second user will wait until lock being released.

I need in next behavior: second user gets error if row under the lock.

Is it possible in DB2 11?

Comment: Your question is Db2-server platform specific (i.e. mainframe Db2 for Z/OS).   When the Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, applications can use the special register setting `set current lock timeout NOT WAIT` to tell Db2 to immediately return an error if Db2 cannot immediately obtain a lock.  This feature is not available currently for Db2 for Z/OS, but other approaches exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is a conditional SELECT if you could get the UPDATE lock if I'm reading your request correctly.  I do not believe there is a way to do that.  However, an alternative you could do something like:

`SELECT myCount FROM myTable WHERE ID = someValue`

You could then update the value and execute the UPDATE with a WHERE clause that looks for the ID and the original value of myCount.  A sequence like

```
SELECT myCount FROM myTable WHERE ID = someValue
origCount = myCount++
UPDATE myTable WHERE ID = someValue AND myCount = origValue
```

If your UPDATE shows zero rows updated you have an indication that someone else updated it and you then repeat the sequence or move on to your alternate logic.

I believe that would achieve what you are looking for without having to detect the presence of a lock since you indicated your accessing a single row at a time you could use CS isolation.

This is generally referred to as [Optimistic Concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)

> Optimistic concurrency control (OCC) is a concurrency control method
>   applied to transactional systems such as relational database
>   management systems and software transactional memory. OCC assumes that
>   multiple transactions can frequently complete without interfering with
>   each other. While running, transactions use data resources without
>   acquiring locks on those resources. Before committing, each
>   transaction verifies that no other transaction has modified the data
>   it has read. If the check reveals conflicting modifications, the
>   committing transaction rolls back and can be restarted.[1] Optimistic
>   concurrency control was first proposed by H.T. Kung and John T.
>   Robinson

Comment: As understand there are only alternative ways doing so. For example this

You cannot reliably prevent other applications from reading a row locked by one application. Queries running with the uncommitted read isolation level will be able to access even exclusively locked rows. Queries running with the cursor stability isolation level using the currently committed semantics will access the previous version of the exclusively locked row.

Best choice is to use a special value (like 'processing') in the status column to prevent other sessions from processing the same row.

Comment: You can prevent them through locking but that sounds like the problem you were trying to avoid.  Here is a reference for Db2 locking semantics.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/perf/src/tpc/db2z_locks4sqlstatements.html .

Answer (score 0):

With a long time to update one record, perhaps better to just read the record including timestamp, then process the other records.  When ready to update, read for update, and if the timestamp has not changed then update the record.  Display an error if the timestamp was changed.